# The background image isn't rendered (locale)

Tags: ionic-framework

When i used image url external it works but with local url it doesn't works

```css
.bgHome{
background: url('../images/bg-login.png') no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
 <ion-view title="'MyApp'" hide-back-button="true" class="bgHome">
```

Comment: I just modified a view I have in a project I'm working on to implement a background exactly as you have above. It worked fine. This might seem like a silly question, but have you looked at your console output to make sure the image is being found?